# Splitting a string with tags, keeping delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I need some helping writing a regex statement to split a string containing some tags (not true HTML, I'm just using using `<i>` and `<b>` tags to format some text), and keep the delimiters. For example this string:

```
<b>a bold quote:</b> this is some sample test. How <i>do</i> I do this?
```

Would be transformed to:

```
<b>a bold quote:</b>
 this is sample text. How 
<i>do</i>
 I do this?
```

Comment: This reminds me of the following stackoverflow classic [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) .. regex-infection wil​l devour your HT​ML parser, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With most regex flavors, you do something close by putting the splitting expression in a capture group.

```
new Regex("(<[^>]+>)").Split("test <b>string</b>")
```

produces an array with the items

```
test  
<b> 
string 
</b>
```

(and an empty string at the end)

If you want to find the things inside the tags, and they're definitely not nested in any way, you can do

```
new Regex("(<[^>]+>[^<]*</[^>]+>)").Split("test <b>string</b>")
```

=

```
test  
<b>string</b>
```

Comment: I'm looking to keep the open/close tags in the same line

Comment: +1. @Jason - unclear what is you comment "keep the open/close tags in the same line" is about... There is nothing in the answer that adds extra new lines...

Comment: Thanks Steve, the second example if what I'm looking for